# What is the appropriate PREPOSITION here

Tags: prepositional-phrases, grammaticality-in-context, sentence-choice

Keep all defective items .....

> 1. It will come **in** my work.
> 2. It will come **to** my work.

Which of the two or something else is suitable in this context?

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding what your sentence is trying to say, and I also don’t know what “Keep all defective items” means here. Can you try to explain a little bit more about what you are trying to express?

Comment: I am saying someone to keep all the defective items because I can do some works with these defective items

Comment: Do you mean that you are asking someone to keep some defective items for you (instead of throwing them out), so that you can use them later?

Comment: Exactly, sir, I am trying to say the same.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to express something like: "Keep all the defective items; they will come in handy **in** my work." So, of the two choices given, the suitable preposition is "in".

Comment: But how does keeping defective items have *anything* to do with the different sentences you give—let alone the prepositions used in them? First, it should be **they**, not **it**. When I read *come to my work*, I understand it to mean *arrive at* or *be mailed to*. Is that what you mean? I also don't know what you mean by *come in my work*.

Answer (score 1):

To say what you are trying to say, I don’t think you should use a prepositional phrase at all. Based on your comments, I would recommend something more along these lines:

> Save all the defective items, because I’ll be able to use them later.
>   Don’t throw away the defects; I can put them to good use.

Some key points that might be helpful:

- On *keep* vs. *save* - Using *keep* makes it sound like you are asking the person to keep these items for their own use. Using *save* makes it more clear that they are not necessarily keeping the items to use themselves.
- On *defects* vs. *defective items* - There is nothing wrong with *defective items*, but sometimes the plural noun *defects* is used as a shorter alternative.
- On *work* vs. *use* - I think *work* is a difficult word to understand in this context. It’s too vague. I had a hard time even guessing at a meaning for your original sentence.
- On *them* vs. *it* - Since you are talking about more than one defective item, you should use a plural pronoun. (You could use *it* there was only one defective item: *Save that defective item; I’ll be able to use it later.*

Comment: But if I would like to use the prepositional phrase, then which of the two is more correct?

Comment: @Kumar - Your sentence with the prepositional phrase made no sense to me. I’m not sure why you’d want to use it if it so difficult to understand.

Comment: I agree with your answer—except that I don't see how it correlates to the two example sentences given in the question. Then again, I'm failing to see how the two example sentences have anything to do with keeping defective items in the first place. (Let alone prepositions.) Those things seem completely separate from each other . . .

Comment: @JasonB - Exactly. I think the OP needs to restructure the sentence, not choose the correct preposition. There is no "correct" preposition in a nonsense sentence.